# Blank pages after installing PHP on IIS

Tags: php, iis-7

I am attempting to install PHP onto Windows Server 2008 R2.  I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/50432/how-to-install-php-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/) but when I try to load phpinfo.php I get a blank page.

There are no errors in the Event Viewer.

The server is used to host multiple other Asp.Net websites but I am using PHP so that I can install MediaWiki.

**UPDATE:**

When trying to load simple HTML (with no PHP) it also loads as blank.  The fix for this seems to be to enable "Static Content" in the "Turn Windows features On/Off" manager - but this is already in place.

Comment: If you view-source the page do you see PHP code (`<?php and ?>`)?

Comment: No its completely blank as if I was loading an empty text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution after hours of randomly trying things.  I removed and re-added the Static Content role in Windows - still same result.  Then I edited the Error Pages feature of the website in IIS to say return Detailed Error Messages.  At this point PHP started to complain about the timezone so I set to "Europe\London" - for this to take effect you need to restart IIS.
After that it worked, phpinfo now loads!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well just running the handy dandy php installer microsoft has on their site using their Web Platform Installer and it turned out in the php.ini file by default short_open_tag by default is off so my code

```
<? 
print("hello world!"); 
?>
```

would not work because it was expecting

```
<?php 
print("hello world!"); 
?>
```

.... so yea ... just go and change that if this is your problem too!

Answer (score 1):

If copying over an old Wordpress installation from an old server - make sure you copy ALL the files. Oops... <embarassed>

Answer (score 0):

A blank page is also possible when there is an PHP error and error reporting is of. Try to run the script below to see what happens.

```
<html>
<body>

Hello HTML

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "Hello PHP";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

You could also try to see if a normal HTML page with PHP extentions runs fine. Perhaps your server is setup to disallow PHP extention.

Comment: I created a file called test.php and added the code above - still blank. I have also create hello.html (containing Hello World) and this returns blank too.  So it seems as though I can't load HTML either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure fastCGI for each PHP website, more details you can find here - [Best Practices for Configuring FastCGI and PHP](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue; at "turn Windows features on or off",  I enabled:
HTTP Errors
Server-Side Includes
Directory Browsing
Windows Authentication

I also set these options in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini:
`display_errors = On`
`display_startup_errors = On`

After that, a 401 Unauthorized error was displayed.  I added 'Everyone' and 'Users' groups to the folder to fix.